# Njs not hitting the flask API

Tags: python, nginx, flask, jwt, njs

In our application, we have a requirement of decrypting the jwt access token that is encrypted using the python Fernet library. We have nginx web server. Using njs, we were able to decode the jwt access token. Before, that we have to decrypt it. Did not find ways to do it from njs.

We created a Flask API and tried to invoke it from njs. The API is successfully working when we invoke it from browser but from njs the Api is not being hit.

Can we get some help on this. Any assistance on this will be a great favor.